# Compute optimal weights in Tobin seperation

Tags: yahoo-finance

I'm having troubles understanding the following:

I understand given, let's say 5 stocks and their historic data, how to compute the efficient frontier of optimal assets. However, when I introduce Tobin separation the confusion starts. Given a constant required return, how do I compute the optimal portfolio when risk-free assets are introduced (e.g. RF=2%), that is the portfolio with lowest standard deviation? For example if I want an expected return of 20%, how do I compute the proportion I should invest in risk-free asset, and the proportion I should invest in my optimal portfolio? From what I understand the optimal portfolio is the tangent point from (0,RF) to the efficient frontier. But I don't understand how to compute the proportion of the optimal portfolio, and the proportion risk-free assets.

Comment: Feels like the quant group might be the right place to ask this

Answer (score 1):

You are right, if we work in the risk-return plane (where risk is on the horizontal axis, expected return on the vertical axis), the optimal stock portfolio is the tangent point from (0,RF) to the efficient frontier of your stocks. Let's say this tangent point has coordinates (sigma_p, R_p), describing the risk and expected return of the optimal stock portfolio. The tangent line is also called the optimal capital allocation line (CAL). Each point on that line corresponds to a mixture of the risk-free asset and the optimal stock portfolio and describes that mixture's risk and expected return.

If you want to achieve a specific expected return, let's say 20%, you find the point where the horizontal line (return=20%) intersects the optimal capital allocation line. Let's say that point has coordinates (s,R). Clearly, R=20%. The mixture you want allocates the fraction s/sigma_p of your money to the optimal stock portfolio and the fraction (1-s/sigma_p) to the risk-free asset.

[Note that 1-s/sigma_p could be negative, in which case the intersection point is located above the efficient frontier and you need to borrow the corresponding amount of money at the risk-free rate and buy the optimal portfolio with that money; you are using leverage and buying the stock portfolio on margin in order to increase your expected return.]